# How to use encrypted userid/passwd in ldap.conf and pam_ldap.conf for proftpd

Tags: linux, ldap, sftp, password-encryption, proftpd

Is there any way to use user/passwd in encrypted form with

```
LDAPUsers user password
```

directive?

If I encrypt "user" and "password", LDAP connection doesn't work. Anything which can be done here?
I am looking for same functionality in pam_ldap.conf.

I've below configuration file ldap.conf used by proftpd service, where LDAPBindDN has "username" and "passwd" in plain text. Target is to to keep them in encrypted format. Anyone who can help me?

```
LDAPServer ""
LDAPBindDN "" ""
LDAPUsers none none
LDAPAuthBinds on
```

Comment: I've created an issue in for the same at https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd/issues/665

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `mod_ldap` module of proftpd does not currently support this kind of functionality.  At best, you could file a feature/enhancement request for it on the [ProFTPD Bugzilla instance](http://bugs.proftpd.org).  Sorry.